# How are foreach executed in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach(func() as $item)...
```

The above will only call `func()` once,but why?What's happening exactly?

Comment: Do you have any code examples to show? With real code, we can help you out more and give a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) is not a control structure with a condition that is tested before or after each iteration like `while`, `for` or `do … while`. Instead it takes an array, makes an copy of it internally and iterates that.

The array can either be passed via a variable (most used variant):

```
foreach ($arr as $val) { /* … */ }
```

Or with another expression that returns an array when evaluated:

```
foreach (array('foo','bar') as $val) { /* … */ }

function f() { return array('foo','bar'); }
foreach (f() as $val) { /* … */ }
```

Comment: It's not a structure,what is it?

Comment: @user198729: I didn’t say it’s not a control structure. I just said it’s not a control structure with a condition that’s tested on every iteration.

Answer (score 7):

foreach accepts an array. You are essentially calling func() once yourself, and passing the resulting array to the foreach construct, which can loop over it.

Comment: I think its evident when you evaluate the `foreach` loop

Comment: to prove it add an echo or log to the function you call in `func()`

Comment: @user198729: You could "prove it" yourself if you ever cared to look at the PHP manual.

Comment: Evidence is anything that you see, experience, read, or are told that causes you to believe that something is true or has really happened

Comment: "phenomenon is not evidence"

I will upvote your question if you prove it exists.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call the function more than once - it should return an array that can be iterated over.